# SQL Database design to check data field out of specification

Tags: sql, database-design

I got a table store measurement records such as temperature, pressure, flow rate, etc. Each entity is recorded by day and locations. For example:

> id, date, location, temperature, pressure, flow rate, ...

Every measurement has its own specifications, for example, the temperature measured value should within the range between 20 to 35, otherwise, the recorded temp value is considered out of specs.

There are many different locations, and for each locations, the specs(data range) of each measurement data is different. For example, Location_1's temp range: 20-35, Location_2's temp range: 15-30.

The need is to be able to count how many records of each measurement data is out of specifications base on different location. I decided to build a specification table. like this:

> id, measurement_name, location, minimum_specs, maximum_specs,
>   nominal_specs,....

My first question is how to create SQL statement to automatically link these two tables, check the specs, then come out the counting result? 
Second question, base on my needs, what could be the other better solutions?

Comment: Is this always a range restriction? Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Are you saying you want to validate data first to see if it can be inserted or updated or should all data be stored and then the second table is used to report on the quality of the data?

Comment: _how to create SQL statement to automatically link these two tables_ - this is called a `join` _base on my needs, what could be the other better solutions_. If there is a lot of data you could go all "big data" and store this is a different data store and run R or python against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem in database designing I suggest your entities to be as following

Records

```
  record_id int auto_increment primary key 
  record_date date
  Location_id foreign key
```

Locations

```
Location_id int auto_increment primary key
Location_name varchar(255)
Temp_Id  foreign Key
Pressure_Id  foreign Key
```

Temperatures

```
  Temp_Id int auto_increment primary key 
  Temp_min_val int 
  Temp_max_val int
```

Pressures

```
  Pressure_id int auto_increment primary key 
  Pressure_min_val int 
  Pressure_max_val int
```

I don't know your database server engine so I can't provide you with sql statements

Comment: please don't forget to mark my answer if it helps you